# How should I fill in the form of a UK Visa for my wife when I have a valid visa?

Tags: visas, uk, family

I was traveling alone to the UK 2 months ago, and my visa is still valid (6 months). Now, for the second time, I want to travel with my wife and daughter, but I wrote in my form, my dependent people will not travel with me to the UK. 
Can I request a visa now for my family and go to the UK with them?
What should I write in my wife and daughter's form for this question: "How much do you want to spend on your travel to the UK"?

Comment: You can mention in their applications that they are travelling with you and that you already have a visa. There are specific questions for that

Answer (score 1):

You have a valid visa and, with that, you're able to travel to the UK. For your wife and daughter to accompany you, they need to apply for their own visas. As part of her application, your wife will be asked about her partner, you, and for your information, including your passport number.

If you are the one underwriting the trip for the whole family, your wife would identify you as that person and include your financial documents showing that there are sufficient funds available, just as you did in your visa application.

You might want to review the [UKVI guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) to make sure you have all your bases covered, before submitting their applications.

Comment: Make sure you include a copy of her visa.

Comment: @greatone who do you mean? She, the wife, doesn't have a visa, nor does his child. He, the husband, does, and doesn't need to include it in the wife's application, as the husband's passport details, which do need to be included, reveal his visa status in the UKVI system.